# Is there a way to compare with certain rows of a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, left-join

These are the relevant tables for my question

```
modules
+--------+
|  code  |
+--------+
| CS1010 |
| CS2030 |
| CS2040 |
| IS3103 |
| IS2101 |
| CS3102 |
+--------+

prereqs
+--------+--------+
| code   | need   |
+--------+--------+
| CS2030 | CS1010 |
| CS2040 | CS1010 |
| IS3103 | IS2101 |
| CS3102 | CS2030 |
| CS3102 | CS2040 |
+--------+--------+

enrolls
+-----------+--------+
|  matric   | code   |
+-----------+--------+
| A0000001A | CS1010 |
| A0000001A | CS2030 |
+-----------+--------+
```

In order to find all the modules (prereqs.code) that a student (enrolls.matric) is able to take, I have used the following query

```
SELECT P.code
FROM enrolls E, prereqs P
WHERE E.matric = 'A0000001A'
  AND P.need IN (SELECT code FROM enrolls)

UNION
    
SELECT M.code
FROM modules M, prereqs P
WHERE M.code NOT IN (SELECT code FROM prereqs)

EXCEPT
    
SELECT code
FROM enrolls
WHERE matric = 'A0000001A';
```

The second subquery (after UNION) handles all modules that have no prerequisites and the third subquery (after EXCEPT) removes all modules that have already been taken by the student (A0000001A).

When running this query, CS3102 shows up as a module that is available for the student to take, this should not be the case as he has only taken CS2030 and not CS2040. In order to be able to take CS3102, the student needs to have taken **both** CS2030 and CS2040. I am not sure how to enforce this constraint with SQL. I am required to use PostgreSQL.

Currently, my query seems to show a module as being available to be taken as long as **one** of it's prequisites have been met. I am unsure how to modify my query to ensure that a module is only shown if **all** its prerequisites are met.

Current output:

```
+--------+
|  code  |
+--------+
| CS2040 |
| CS3102 |
| IS2101 |
+--------+
```

Desired output:

```
+--------+
|  code  |
+--------+
| CS2040 |
| IS2101 |
+--------+
```

Comment: My first thoughts are that I need to use a GROUP BY on the statements and then somehow check that all of its prereqs are fulfilled

Comment: what is your desired output

Comment: @Fahmi edited the original post to include these details and more necessary information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach using `not exists` and `left join`s:

```
select m.code
from modules m
left join prereqs pr on pr.code = m.code
left join enrolls e  on e.code = pr.need and e.matric = 'A0000001A'
where not exists (select 1 from enrolls e where e.code = m.code and e.matric = 'A0000001A')
group by m.code
having count(pr.code) = count(e.code)
```

The `not exists` condition filters out modules that the given matric has already taken. On the other hands, the `left join`s bring the prequesites and the corresponding enrollments, and the `having` clause ensures that they are all fulfilled.

Comment: This works! Thanks for the help. I will have to do more research on  LEFT JOIN cos im not sure what that does right now :')

Answer (score 0):

i believe you can proceed with a kind of double negation, in place of the first and second part of your query. Something like this

```
SELECT P.code
FROM prereqs P
WHERE not exists (
      select 1 from prereqs p2 where p2.code=P.code and p2.code not in (
          select code from enrolls E where E.matric = 'A0000001A'
      )
)
```